# Relate existence of common invariant subspace of $m$ matrices to reducibility of certain polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's recall a linear algebra fact: Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over a field $K$ and $\chi_A(t)$ be its characteristic polynomial. Then if $\chi_A(t)$ is reducible, $A$ would have a proper invariant subspace.

My intention is to find an analogy in the case of $m$ matrices. That is, given $m$ $n\times n$ matrices $A_1, A_2,\cdots , A_m$, can we find a polynomial $p$, with several variable maybe, so that if $p$ is reducible, then $A_1, A_2,\cdots , A_m$ have common invariant subspace.

A reasonable way to do this is to consider the polynominal $D(x_1,\cdots, x_m)=det(x_1a_1+\cdots+ x_mA_m)$. So clearly if D is irreducible, then $A_1, A_2,\cdots , A_m$ would have NO common invariant subspaces. However, it is mentioned by David E Speyer in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184960/invariant-subspaces-if-f-is-defined-by-more-than-one-matrix/185001) that the converse of this statement is in general not true.

My questions are:

(1) Where can I find the example to the case: $D(x_1,\cdots, x_m)$ is reducible while $A_1, A_2,\cdots , A_m$ have no common invariant subspace? If I choose $n$ large enough, is there such example also?

(2) Do we have other kind of polynomials suit this problem? For example, one can consider the polynomial $det(X_1\otimes A_1+\cdots +X_m\otimes A_m)$ whose variables are entries of $X_1,\cdots, X_m$ (These kind of function are semi-invariants of certain Kronecker quiver representation).

Comment: As a particular case of your question, you might like to read about the group determinant. When the $A_{i}$ form a group, the group determinant goes a long way to answering your question.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Thanks for comment! I read about the group determinant and I realize that the group determinant can be "defined" for any finite dimensional algebra(in my case I would consider the algebra generated by $A_i$) in the following way: find a linear basis $e_1, \cdots ,e_n$, form a matrix with entry $a_{ij}=e_ie_j$(and then express in terms of linear combination of $\{e_k\}$). If I regard $e_i$ as variables, then can the determinant of $(a_{ij})$ tell something?

Comment: I suppose it carries some information, but I am not sure how much.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Consider the algebra $\mathscr{A}$ generated by $\{A_i\}$, then the vector space $K^n$ is an $\mathscr{A}$ module. So if we have a nontrivila subalgebra of $\mathscr{A}$, then we would have a submodule of $K^n$, which is a common invariant subspace of $\{A_i\}$. If the matrix $(a_{ij})$ above is similar to a blocked upper trianglar matrix, then we would have a subalgebra. So the question reduces to(which is somehow my original question): if I have a $n\times n$ matrix over a UFD,  and its determinant is reducible, is it similar to a blocked upper trianglar matrix?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson After I add the comment above, I realize that I am not so sure about the "If the matrix (aij) above is similar to a blocked upper trianglar matrix, then we would have a subalgebra" part